# Init function breaking unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, go

In the package I want to test, I have an init function that loads the configuration file containing some stuff I want to use to run my application. However, I don't want to trigger this init function while running my unit tests.

Is there any way for skipping or preventing this init function to be called during the unit tests?

Some snippets to illustrate the question:

```
func init() {
    var err error // Necessary to prevent config variable shadowing
    config, err = loadConfig("./client/config.yml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func loadConfig(filepath string) (*Config, error) {
    viper.SetConfigFile(filepath)
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error loading config file: %s", err)
    }
  (...)
}

// New returns a Config value(!)
func New() Config {
    return *config
}
```

A test case:

```
func TestNew(t *testing.T) {
    expected := &Config{}
    observed := New()
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(observed, expected) {
        t.Errorf("observed %+v. expecting %+v\n", observed, expected)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against loading your configuration in an init() function at all, for the reason stated (issues with testing) among others (structure, reusability, control, etc.). Just call loadConfig() from your entry point.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure whether there's a nicer way of doing this, but if you consider the fact that package-level variables are initialized before the `init` func is run you can use a flag to tell you whether you're running tests or not.

```
var _testing = false

func init() {
    if _testing {
        return
    }

    var err error // Necessary to prevent config variable shadowing
    config, err = loadConfig("./client/config.yml")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// ...
```

And in your test file you could do something like this:

```
// not nice but works
var _ = (func() interface{} {
    _testing = true
    return nil
}())

func TestNew(t *testing.T) {
    expected := &Config{}
    observed := New()
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(observed, expected) {
        t.Errorf("observed %+v. expecting %+v\n", observed, expected)
    }
}
```

You can read more on the initialization order here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've decided to not use the `init()`. Calling `loadConfig` in the `New` function and return also an error in that function seems more appropriated.

Comment: For some context I used this for testing GCP cloud functions. As my function's global dependencies are initialised in `func init()`, with this approach I can mock them first in the test file and the only change to the real code is to check if deps are already initialised, and if so, skip the real initialisation. If anyone has a better or more "proper" way I'm all ears