# getting cross-package coverage in golang without init() running

Tags: go, testing, go-cobra, go-testing

I have inherited a very large, very old golang codebase. I'm trying to get coverage stats and most of the tests are testing across packages.

If I run `go test ./...` the tests pass.

If i run `go test -coverpkg=./... ./...` then the tests fail because all the
the `init()` functions are executed during the tests. (It's failing in a bunch of cobra cmd that don't even have tests). The `init()` do things that cause the tests to fail.

Is there a way to get the init() to not happen when collecting coverage just like a normal test run?

Comment: Is there an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409919/init-function-breaking-unit-tests/43410591